# Simple PHP search query

Tags: php, mysql, forms, search

I'm trying to make a simple search query script, that will pull results from a form and return results from a database accordingly.

**'connect.php'**

```
<?php

$strServer = "http://server33.000webhost.com";
$strDatabase = "******";
$strUser = "******";
$strPwd = "******";

$strDB = mysql_connect($strServer, $strUser, $strPwd) or die ("Could not connect to database"); print mysql_error();
$database = mysql_select_db("$strDatabase", $strDB); print mysql_error();   
?>
```

**'search.php'**

```
<?php

ini_set ('display_errors', 1);

include ('connect.php'); print mysql_error();

$query = ('SELECT * FROM 'properties' WHERE ('type' = '$_POST['type']') OR ('area' = '$_POST['area']')');
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Couldn't execute query."); print mysql_error();

while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo $r['type'];
echo $r['area'];
}
?>
```

I've searched countless forums and tutorials, and can't see what I'm doing wrong. Please please help me! Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you've got conflicting quotes on the `$query` line, you're using `mysql_*` functions, and your SQL query is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: He's using single quotes for the query string, the same being used for the SQL. Here is one problem: 'SELECT * FROM 'properties' ...', it should be 'SELECT * FROM \'properties\' ...'

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to Change your query like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `properties` 
          WHERE (`type` = '".mysql_escape_string($_POST['type'])."') 
          OR (`area` = '".mysql_escape_string($_POST['area'])."')";
```

And try to avoid mysql_* functions,better to use mysqli and try mysql_escape_string for the post and get values

Comment: Any reason to downvote it..??

Comment: You're putting unsantized parameters into your query. It's vulnerable to SQL injection. While you're answering OP's question, you should at least say something about the huge security hole his script has.

Comment: its correct only..whu would anyone downvote it..

Comment: @Blender in case u didn't notice he mentioned to avoid mysql functions.. as their work around for injections is weird `mysql_escape_string` and use ,mysqli functions..

Comment: Yah @RajatSinghal i have edited with that.thnku Blender I forgoted to put that one...thanku so much

Comment: And nobody says he can't sanitize the strings when reading them instead of saving ( htmlspecialchars(), htmlentities(), etc...)

Comment: @AlejandroIván "Nope, there is no function in mySQL to decode html entities since it is not concerned with html" you can add them as per your code and need,if we need all the things as ans for this particular question We can add htmlentities(),htmlspecialchars(),mysql_resl_escape_string all

Comment: I didn't meant that, sorry. What I tried to say is that he doesn't really need to sanitize strings when inserting them. He can sanitize them when reading with PHP and using PHP functions to do that. Anyway, I guess it depends on the programmer.

Comment: yah you are right,but anyway your point is also very imp,bec in this logical world,if we need securable and defaultless widget we need to add all,and need to check all perspectives

Comment: @Gautam3164 Thanks for the response :)

I've tried changing the above code, but it's still not working. I'm now getting the error 'Couldn't execute query.'

here is my code again..

search.php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
include ('connect.php'); print mysql_error();
$query = "SELECT * FROM 'properties' WHERE ('type' = '".mysql_escape_string($_POST['type'])."') OR ('area' =  ".mysql_escape_string($_POST['area'])."')";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Couldn't execute query."); print mysql_error();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
 {
 echo $r['type'];
 echo $r['area'];
 }

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you should review:
    include ('connect.php'); print mysql_error();

it is best to not use mysql_error() at standalone statement. Anyway theres not much need of mysql error here in search.php page. One more correction you may make is: (connection.php)
    $database = mysql_select_db("$strDatabase", $strDB) or die("error while connecting to database".mysql_error());

Lastly, all the parsing error you might be getting is due to this statement.

$query = ('SELECT * FROM 'properties' WHERE ('type' = '$_POST['type']') OR ('area' = '$_POST['area']')');

When you start a string block with ' then the end of block is also '. Next, two strings cannot be simply concatenated, you must use . symbol.

ie

```
$a='make me'.'good'; //valid
$b='hello'$a'!!thanks'; // invalid
$b='hello'.$a.'!!thanks'; //valid (concatenation is used here with . sign)

$otherway="hello {$a} !!thanks"; //valid
```

so your code can be written as

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 'properties' WHERE 'type' = '$_POST['type']' OR 'area' = '$_POST['area']'";
```

This is because " starts and " ends the string but it doesnot care about ' inside the program.